Why does JsPDF.html() not render html content?
  const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

  const style = $(`
<style>
    body{
        color: black
    }
</style>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam at. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae. In est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt. Vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id. Tristique magna sit amet purus gravida quis. Et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies mi. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu. Dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit amet volutpat consequat. Vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Tempor orci dapibus ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue. Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent tristique magna. Eget lorem dolor sed viverra ipsum. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non. Sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec.
</p>

`)

  pdf.html(style.html(), {
    callback: function (doc) {
      pdf.save('myfile.pdf');
    },
    autoPaging: 'text',
    jsPDF: pdf,
    windowWidth: 1000,
    width: 1000
  });

The output from this is 
